# text overlay not sizing with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overlay

I have a flexbox with a text overlay on top and everything looks fine when the browser is full width:

[image]

However, when I shrink the browser to smaller width, the overlay becomes wider than the image:
[image]

My HTML looks like this:

```
<a ng-if="::(options.link_template == 'Picture')" ng-href="{{::data.href}}" class="picture {{::options.class_name}}" target="{{::data.target}}">
    <img src="{{::options.picture}}" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <h3><span>{{::options.title}}</span></h3>   
</a>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
a.picture {
  position: relative; 
   //width: 100%;
   display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}

a.picture img {
    width: 360px;
  height: 238px;
}

a.picture > h3 {
    margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

a.picture > h3 span {
     display: block;
   color: white; 
   font-weight: bold;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(51, 103, 150, 0.6);
   padding: 10px; 
}
```

What am I missing from my CSS so that the overlay "locks" in with the image?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of parent container equal to the image size.

```css
 a.picture {
      position: relative; 
       width: 360px;
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       align-items: center;
       justify-content: center;
    }
    
    a.picture img {
     width: 360px;
      height: 238px;
    }
    
    a.picture > h3 {
     margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    
    a.picture > h3 span {
      display: block;
       color: white; 
       font-weight: bold;  
       background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
       background: rgba(51, 103, 150, 0.6);
       padding: 10px; 
    }
```

```html
<a class="picture">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/1510/road-sky-sand-street.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  <h3><span>Content</span></h3>
</a>
```

Comment: that worked! quick follow up question, is there a way to use flexboxes so that the images are the same width and height without specifying actual height and width dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean by same width and height? A square? Also, "without specifying actual height and width dimensions" of what ? The image? Or the parent?

Comment: so instead of me specifying that the width is 360px and height is 238px for example, is there a way to just use flexbox so that all the images are the same dimensions.  I want the images to fill the entire space in the parent, but I want the parents to be the same dimensions, does that make sense?

Comment: You don't want to specify "width as 360px and height as 238px" for `<img>` and make the `<img>` as large as the parent container, right? In that case, you WILL need the dimensions of parent container, and then you need to set the dimensions of `img` as `100%`. This will stretch the image to fit the parent container, without maintaining `aspect-ratio`.